# Spark out of memory because of values in map function?

Tags: scala, memory-leaks, apache-spark

I have written the following spark job to compare large numbers of textfiles for duplicated paragraphs. I am new to spark and wondering if I have a memory leak because I sometimes run into Out of memory GC exceptions.

```
  val conf = ConfigFactory.load()
  val partitionsCount = conf.getInt("simtext.partitions")
  val minMatchLength = conf.getInt("simtext.minmatchlength")
  val hdfsDir1 = conf.getString("simtext.hdfs.dir1")
  val hdfsDir2 = conf.getString("simtext.hdfs.dir2")
  val outputDir = conf.getString("simtext.hdfs.output")

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("simtext4s with Spark")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val tokenizer = new Tokenizer()

    val tokenizedFiles1 = getTokenizedFilesAsRdd(sc, tokenizer, hdfsDir1)
    val tokenizedFiles2 = getTokenizedFilesAsRdd(sc, tokenizer, hdfsDir2)

    val comparetuples: RDD[CompareTuple] = tokenizedFiles1.cartesian(tokenizedFiles2).map {
      case ((name1, tokens1), (name2, tokens2)) =>
        CompareTuple(TokenizedText(name1, tokens1), TokenizedText(name2, tokens2))
    }

    val results: RDD[CompareResult] = comparetuples.map { compareTuple =>
      val forwardRefTable: SortedMap[Int, Int] = buildForwardReferenceTable(
        compareTuple.combinedTokens,
        minMatchLength
      )
      val similarity: Double = compareTokenLists(
        compareTuple.splitIndex,
        forwardRefTable,
        minMatchLength
      )
      CompareResult(compareTuple.tokenizedText1.name, compareTuple.tokenizedText2.name, similarity)
    }

    results.saveAsTextFile(outputDir)

    sc.stop()
  }
```

buildForwardRefTable is a method in the same object like the main method:

```
def buildForwardReferenceTable(tokens: List[String], minMatchLength: Int): SortedMap[Int, Int] = {
  val (_, forwardRefTable) = tokens
    .sliding(minMatchLength)
    .zipWithIndex
    .foldLeft(HashMap.empty[List[String], Int], SortedMap.empty[Int, Int]) {
      case ((lastIndexAcc, forwardRefTableAcc), (slice, index: Int)) =>
        if (lastIndexAcc.contains(slice)) {
          val updatedForwardRefTable = forwardRefTableAcc + (lastIndexAcc.get(slice).get -> index)
          val updatedLastIndexAcc = lastIndexAcc + (slice -> index)
          (updatedLastIndexAcc, updatedForwardRefTable)
        } else {
          val updatedLastIndexAcc = lastIndexAcc + (slice -> index)
          (updatedLastIndexAcc, forwardRefTableAcc)
        }
    }

    forwardRefTable
  }
```

My question is about the map function in the main method that creates the results value.
It generates for each comparetuple an forward reference table to compare the texts. Does ist store these forward reference tables until the whole map function on all comparetuples is done? Because the behaviour that I would like to have is that it generates the forward reference table and removes it from memory after computing the similarity.

Are there any other big mistakes that could lead to a memory leak? This is my first spark job.

Comment: How `buildForwardReferenceTable` is implemented? Looks like potential source for leak

Comment: I have added the code of the buildForwardReferenceTable function